# Why does "on top of" lack of an article before "top"?

Tags: prepositions

I read in a children's book, Bliff’s fun phonics:

> "The duck is on top."

"Top" is supposed to be countable. Why is there not an article before "top" in the phrase?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20top

Comment: Why is the question closed? Why is this question more suitable in English Language Learners site? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

The players:

- **[top](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20top&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)** is a noun that means "the highest point"
- **[on](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20on&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=define%20o&sc=8-8&sk=&cvid=42759D81C1194EFC92D31923D813D743)** is a preposition meaning "to be in physical contact with"
- "The duck..." is the **[subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar))** of this sentence.
- "...is on top." is the **[predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar))** of this sentence.

---

> *"Top" is supposed to be countable.*

Not really. "Top" is just "top" and most things only have 1 top, tautologically speaking (there can only be 1 highest point). There is a separate noun, a *top*, like a *spinning top*, such as a dreidel, which could be countable. You could have 3 tops, so to speak, of that kind. You cannot have 3 tops to 1 duck.

"*On top*" is an established [**prepositional phrase**](https://www.thoughtco.com/parts-of-a-prepositional-phrase-1689686), such as "*by the way*" or "*in side*", the former having become a hackneyed idiom and the latter going so far as to become 1 word.

There is no need to add an article if the context is sufficient to determine *what* the duck is on top *of*.

If you were being very expressive, here is an example scenario where a definite article might appear:

> Where is the duck?
>
> > The duck is on the house.
>
> Yes, but, where on the house is the duck?
>
> > On the top.

I don't think you would see this expression with an indefinite article outside of farfetched or idiosyncratic instances.

---

Note another interesting example:

> "We put the flag on the top of the mountain."
>
> "We put the flag on top of the mountain."

The first sentence implies that the speaker ***[summitted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summit)*** the mountain and placed the flag *at the (very) top*. The second sentence could mean the same thing, to a lazy speaker and a lazy listener; it could also be a joke that the speaker put the flag "somewhere on top of the geographical feature of the mountain, but not necessarily *the* top."

Comment: You say that _top_ is “not really” supposed to be countable, but then you immediately use it as a count noun (“1 top”). _Countable_ (or _count noun_) does not mean that there is more than one that you can count, but rather that you can use the plural form, and that the singular requires an article or similar determiner. Non-count (or mass) nouns are things like _furniture_ or _cutlery_ are the opposite: you cannot say ‘two furnitures’ or ‘a cutlery’. _Top_ is indeed normally a count noun.

Comment: Good point. You could be poetic and say "the tops of mountains". But it seems wrong to say like "People wore hats on the tops of their heads." Also, purportedly uncountable nouns can be made plural readily, I find, like "We sailed the boat through the many waters of the world" or "A city is an amalgam of the cultures of the peoples that have lived therein"

Comment: Nouns are count or non-count by default, but many (most, perhaps?) non-count nouns can be ‘countified’ in various situations; some count nouns can also be ‘massified’. _Top_ is count by default, but I cannot think of a context where massifying it would work. (Also, something can have more than one top; a sinus curve, for example.)

Comment: Just to throw the spanner in, I think "People wore hats on the tops of their heads" is the most correct.

Comment: @marcellothearcane hm, maybe, but dont you think "People wear hats on the top of their heads" also works as a declarative , despite the *seeming* lack of parallelism? The object class called "People" wear the object class called "hats" on the "top" (value attribute hence lack of declension) of their (3rd plu --or 3rd singular--) head/s (plu)